# How to switch language in WordPress "on-the-fly"

Tags: wordpress, switch-statement, translation

Is there a way like `switch_to_blog()` for switching the language in WordPress.

Something like

```
global $locale
$currentLanguage = $locale;
switch_to_language('de_DE');

//do some action with german localisation

switch_to_language($currentLanguage);
```

Is this possible in general with WordPress?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I finally found the solution. The function is called `load_textdomain()`

This is how it's done on my side. Keep in mind to define `LANGUAGE_PATH` and the language you would like to switch to in `$new_language`. `$your_domain` is the text domain of your plugin/theme

```
//will output "Good Morning"
_e('Good Morning', $your_domain);

global $locale;
//save the current language for later
$current_language = $locale;
$new_language = 'DE_de';

//load the new text domain
load_textdomain( $your_language_domain, LANGUAGE_PATH.'/'.$your_domain.'-'.$new_language.'.mo' );

//do some action with the new localisation
//will output "Guten Morgen"
_e('Good Morning', $your_domain);

//go back to the previous language
load_textdomain( $your_language_domain , LANGUAGE_PATH.'/'.$your_domain.'-'.$current_language.'.mo' );
```

Took a while to find this method in the core. Read more about that function on [the codex site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_textdomain)

Comment: Do you know if this still works? I can't get it to work myself. I've got a site in Swedish where every text string is run through _e() or __() in English. On certain posts/pages I'd like to render all text in English rather than Swedish so I'm just trying to do what you do above but the output isn't changed. I am using a child theme if that changes things?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work if you switch back to `en_US`. You could change `$your_domain` to a random string so the translation is not registered and uses the fallback - English

Comment: That's actually how I ended up solving it :P It's not perfect - and only works for English obviously - but at least it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're going to need a plugin for that. WordPress doesn't do that out of the box.
WPML is usually the go-to multi-lingual plugin for WordPress, you should check it out :)

Comment: But how a plugin does it? I don't actually need the `switch_to_language()` function. If I just change the global $local it doesn't work

Comment: You can't change a defined constant; that's not going to work. You could change the locale variable after that with the 'locale' filter. See here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52419/setting-wplang-from-a-plugin

Comment: check my final answer. This is how I made it and how it works. I just have to switch the language temporarily and not for the whole request

Comment: You can use add_filter to change the language and then remove_filter te get back to the default...

Comment: not when the filter was already applied - which is in my case